# /etc/vsftpd.conf file not found

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

So I'm trying to setup vsFTPd on my Ubuntu server. I did `aptitude install vsftpd` to install the program, but when I go to `/etc/` to look for the `vsftpd.conf` file, it isn't there.  Is there a way that I can get it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced similar problems (form time to time). Mostly If I had a previous or a partial installation of a package, sometimes a new installation from apt-get or aptitude may miss some of the configuration files.

To get the original /etc/vsftpd.conf I would do the following (assuming that you already have the deb file in /var/cache/apt/archives/ - in my example I'll do with natty's version)

```
~$ cd /tmp
~$ ar x /var/cache/apt/archives/vsftpd_2.3.2-3ubuntu4_i386.deb data.tar.gz
~$ tar xvf data.tar.gz ./etc/vsftpd.conf
```

If you follow those steps you should end with your file at

```
/tmp/etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

1. it's probably located in /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
2. find / -name vsftpd.conf

Comment: Nope, nothing related to vsftpd in /etc/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the vsftpd.conf that is created by default in Ubuntu 10.10

http://paste.org/pastebin/view/32278

Not sure why you didn't get it, just copy and paste this into a file, save it to that path, and see where you get to.

It will most likely log to /var/log/daemon.log with startup information, you can check that after doing

```
service vsftpd restart
```

This should get you started at least!